# Mount a Symlink Directory to Document Root for Deployment

Tags: security, mount, deployment, user-permissions, symlink

Trying to establish a secure multiuser environment with limited user permissions and automated deployment.  The example has been made simple to express the idea.

Docroot: `/var/www/site/staging/current/public`
Deploy user `site-staging:staging`
Home directory:  `/home/site-staging`

The deploy tool creates two directories - releases and current.  Current is a sym link to a releases subdirectory which changes on every site update.

Current is then `mount -a` to the document root which actually mounts the release directory since you can't mount a symlink.

`#/etc/fstab

/var/www/site/staging/current  /home/site-staging/current  none  rw,bind`

Keep in mind the current directory is a symlink and would require a umount and remount everytime the site is deployed / updated.

How can I limit the deploy user to their home directory (chroot) while also automatically mounting the current directory to docroot?

Is that the only option?  Is there a better strategy?

Comment: @Gilles do you have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your home directory /home/site-staging/current as your docroot. Then every time you deploy and recreate the current symlink toward your release your site will updated.

Comment: unfortunately the DocumentRoot should be current/public.  This allows items in the project to be placed outside the document root.  I don't believe the DocRoot can be a symlinked subdirectory like current/public is.  Am I wrong on this?  This was not shown correctly in the intial question  but is updated.

Comment: I'll test it later but I'm pretty sure that you can set your DocRoot to a subdirectory of a symlink as long as you enable Options FollowSymLinks in your apache config or vhost definition.

Comment: In my setup, the parent 2 levels above DocumentRoot required the Options Symlinks Directive.  So <Directory /var/www/site/staging/>Options FollowSymLinks</Directory>